# Android: retrieving data bundle within another fragment activity

Tags: android-activity, bundle

I am trying to retrieve some data in a bundle created within one activity from another fragment activity

Data is entered into the first screen, then the next screen (containing the fragment) retrieves it via activityCallbacks.

I can't even get the parent activity of the second screen to return my data.

Am i doing this right?

In the first screen, the data is packaged into a bundle as follows:

```
Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
dataBundle.putInt("myInt", 9);
```

I have tried this in the parent activity of the second screen i am using:

```
    Bundle myBundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    tvDBG = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDBG);
    tvDBG.setText(""+myBundle.getInt("MyInt"));
```

This is just causing a crash.

should i be using the asset manager instead and if so how?

Answer (score 0):

```
Bundle bundle=getArguments(); 
int mvalue = bundle.getInt("myInt", 0);
```

you also check  spelling for "myInt"